# Load testing video streaming with Loadrunner

Tags: load, load-testing, loadrunner

I would like to test load streaming of multiple users.
The streaming is for a m3u8 file (I can see the video with VLC player).
I am using HP Loadrunner.

Any suggestions ?

Koby.

Comment: Did you try recording with the protocol adviser?

Comment: Whenever I try recording the VLC with protocol adviser, LR crashes :(. It'v version 11.5 which is known to crash occasionally.

Comment: I was able to run protocol adviser with VLC in version 12.01(beta) and I streamed Youtube. I got WebHttp as a result. I recorded with WebHttp and it worked out pretty well creating async steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to record the streaming with HTTP protocol. Streaming appears as multiple HTTP GET requests, one for each video bulk.